# scope using html object tag

Tags: javascript, html, object, scope

I have an HTML file, **parent.html** which has a link to a javascript file **code.js** with a whole lot of functionality in it.

The HTML file **parent.html** also loads another HTML page using the `<object>`tag.
This file is called **child.html**. It makes reference to the code which is in **code.js**. It calls a function when a button is clicked in the **child.html** file.

I keep getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError".

How can I fix this issue?

I thought that because my js file was added to the parent level file, that it would be accessible to the children files.

Comment: Have you checked all the spellings in the code? It will better if you post the code.

Comment: Can you try window.parent.properyName to access it?

Comment: I am trying to call a function...

Comment: I have double checked the spelling as well, and it is ok.

Comment: @BruceHerbert seems you are referring to a function which is not in the global scope.

Comment: @Jai, I thought that it would be in the global scope because it was in the parent file...

Comment: Well that can be something like you have referenced to the function but included it later/after the elemnt which is bound.

Comment: Can you add the piece of code related to `parent.html which has a link to a javascript file code.js` in order to see the way you added the script to the HTML document? And add also the piece of code related to <object> tag to see how this does reference your child.html file. Is parent.html, child.html and code.js coming from the same domain?

Comment: <Object> tag includes the html page as seperate HTML Document Thats why you couldn't get the scope of the method.

Comment: @siva - that makes sense, thanks:)